# Json Parsing in C# without creating class

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I want to read a given json and display the value of `"value"` parameter only for the Array name that contains string `"PL_DATA_HL"`.

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "PL_DATA_HL_XYZ": [
        {
          "name": "$.properties.start",
          "value": "new password"
        },
        {
          "name": "$.properties.end",
          "value": "2017-04-20T00:30:00Z"
        },
    ],
    "PL_DATA_IL_HGF": [
        {
          "name": "$.properties.start",
          "value": "2017-05-21T01:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "$.properties.end",
          "value": "2017-05-21T01:00:00Z"
        },
    ],
    "PL_DATA_HL_ABC": [
        {
          "name": "$.properties.start",
          "value": "new password"
        },
        {
          "name": "$.properties.end",
          "value": "2017-04-20T00:30:00Z"
        },
    ],
 }
```

I already tried using below code, but seems not working!

```
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var set in jsonObj)
{
   Console.WriteLine(set.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recheck the structure and your code will looks like:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var set in jsonObj)
{
    if(Convert.ToString(set.Name).Contains("PL_DATA_HL"))
        foreach (var sub in set.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sub.value);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the property name of each element in the root object. Considering that you have to check the property name it's a better idea to navigate throught the properties of `JObject` instead of the `dynamic` (you should use Reflection in this case).

Something like this should work:

```
JObject jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
foreach (var property in jsonObj.Properties())
{
    if (property.Name.StartsWith("PL_DATA_HL"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property: " + property.Name);

        JArray array = (JArray)property.Value;

        foreach (JObject values in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + values.GetValue("name"));
            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + values.GetValue("value"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
foreach (var jsonArr in jsonObj)
        {
            if (jsonArr.Key.StartsWith("PL_DATA_HL"))
            {
                foreach (var elem in jsonObj[jsonArr.Key])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(elem["value"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a way is to use `Regex` like this:

```
var values =
    Regex.Matches(json, @"""PL_DATA_HL[^]]+]")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .SelectMany(c=> Regex.Matches(c.ToString(), @"(?<=""value"")\s*:\s*""(?<value>[^""]+)""")
        .OfType<Match>().Select(m=> m.Groups["value"].ToString()))
        .ToList();
```

[**[ C# Demo ]**](http://rextester.com/CEZGC51528)

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :

```
string json = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Sample.json"))
{
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
}
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var set in jsonObj)
{
    if ((set).Name.Contains("PL_DATA_HL"))
    {
        object value = (set).Value;
        dynamic jsonValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Values for " + (set).Name);
        foreach (var jsonValue in jsonValues)
        {
            var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonValue.ToString());
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if((item).Name == "value")
                    Console.WriteLine((item).Value);
            }
        }                    
    }
}
```